# How do i control listview item details?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

I have 2 pages with their own listviews. I need all the details of the first listview item to be added to the other listview when it is selected. Thank you for any help on my vague question.

```
public async void OnTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new TeamPage());
}
```

So, when an item is tapped it switches to the other page but want the selected item to be added to the TeamPage listview. All the details of the items are bound to an IList.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Rather than leave the question vague as you have noted try to include enough detail to help us help you. Including whatever code you have tried so far often helps narrow things down.

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow, Please take a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?)

Comment: Does the "it" in "when it is selected" refer to the first listview?

Comment: do you understand how to respond to a listview's ItemSelected event?  Do you know how to navigate from one page to another?  Do you know how to pass parameters to a page?  Do you know how to display items in a ListView?  Those are the major operations needed to accomplish what you're asking.  It would be helpful if you explained which of those pieces you don't know how to accomplish.

Comment: Hopefully my edit clears things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you want to tap ListView Item, then navigate to another page, display the tapped item in this page listview, am I right? If yes, I do one sample that you can take a look:

Page 1:

```
   <StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding model3s}" ItemTapped="ListView_ItemTapped">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Id}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>

public partial class Page11 : ContentPage
{

    public ObservableCollection<model3> model3s { get; set; }
    public Page11 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        model3s = new ObservableCollection<model3>()
        {
            new model3(){Id=1,FirstName="Cherry",LastName="Bu",Description="Age is 28, class is A"},
            new model3(){Id=2,FirstName="Barry",LastName="Bu",Description="Age is 32, class is B"},
            new model3(){Id=3,FirstName="Wendy",LastName="Bu",Description="Age is 25, class is C"},
            new model3(){Id=4,FirstName="Stnfan",LastName="Bu",Description="Age is 27, class is A"},
            new model3(){Id=5,FirstName="Annie",LastName="Bu",Description="Age is 28, class is B"},
            new model3(){Id=6,FirstName="Mattew",LastName="Bu",Description="Age is 25, class is C"},
            new model3(){Id=7,FirstName="Amy",LastName="Bu",Description="Age is 29, class is A"},
            new model3(){Id=8,FirstName="Elvis",LastName="Bu",Description="Age is 32, class is B"},
        };
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

    private async void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var content = e.Item as model3;
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Page12(content));
    }
}

public class model3
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Page2:

```
<StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="listview1" ItemsSource="{Binding collection}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Description}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>

public partial class Page12 : ContentPage
{
   public ObservableCollection<model3> collection { get; set; }

    public Page12 (model3 content)           
    {

        InitializeComponent ();
        collection = new ObservableCollection<model3>();
        collection.Add(content);


        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! That's exactly what i need. Works like a charm.